# Antlr rule with parameter

Tags: antlr

I'm struggle with ANTLR rule parameters. ANTLR version is 4.4.

```
grammar A;
DIGIT: [0-9];
s: val EOF;
val: dval[1] | val '*' val;
dval[int  x]: '.';
```

ANTLR fails with

```
error(50): :2:32: syntax error: '1' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for rule element 
/Users/parrt/antlr/code/antlr4/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/parse/GrammarTreeVisitor.g: node from after line 2:10 no viable alternative at input 'dval<tokenIndex=22>' 
/Users/parrt/antlr/code/antlr4/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/parse/GrammarTreeVisitor.g: node from after line 2:10 no viable alternative at input 'dval<tokenIndex=22>' 
/Users/parrt/antlr/code/antlr4/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/parse/GrammarTreeVisitor.g: node from after line 2:10 no viable alternative at input 'dval<tokenIndex=22>'
```

But the similar grammar without the rule parameter is processed well.

```
grammar A;
DIGIT: [0-9];
s: val EOF;
val: dval | val '*' val;
dval: '.';
```

Comment: How come you were able to see error? What antlr compiler command you ran?

Comment: @daneel-s-yaitskov do you have any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR does not support params in rule definitions.

Parser rules consist of a set of lexer rules or parser rules, see https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md

```
dval[int  x]: '.';
```

is not a valid rule.

#### Suggestion

[The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference/) is a great book to known about ANTLR.
Also, [grammars-v4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) is a good reference for learning ANTLR grammars.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR does allow for rule arguments, but they don't work the way I suspect you are expecting.  This is a revised version of your grammar (I'm guessing a bit at your intentions). Also, note: this is just using the `returns` annotation of the rule.
(For a more complete answer on passing arguments, you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21747790/73764)

```
grammar A;

s: val EOF;
val returns [int value]: INT | INT '*' INT;
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
INT: DIGIT+;
WS: [ \t\n] -> skip;
```

running the input `89*10` through this, gives the tree `(val 89 * 10)`

[image]

The `returns [int value]` part simply adds `value` to your `ValContext`.  This gives you a variable to place the calculated value when you call a listener (overriding the `void exitVal(AParser.ValContext ctx);` method.

```java
    public static class ValContext extends ParserRuleContext {
        public int value;
        public List<TerminalNode> INT() { return getTokens(AParser.INT); }
        public TerminalNode INT(int i) {
            return getToken(AParser.INT, i);
        }
        public ValContext(ParserRuleContext parent, int invokingState) {
            super(parent, invokingState);
        }
        @Override public int getRuleIndex() { return RULE_val; }
        @Override
        public void enterRule(ParseTreeListener listener) {
            if ( listener instanceof AListener ) ((AListener)listener).enterVal(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void exitRule(ParseTreeListener listener) {
            if ( listener instanceof AListener ) ((AListener)listener).exitVal(this);
        }
    }
```

This is detailed in *The Definitive ANTLR Reference* in the "Annotating Parse Trees" section of chapter 7.  Also see "Rule Attribute Definitions" in chapter 15 (If you're going to do much with ANTLR, this books is very approachable and an invaluable reference)